# Testflight: This build is incompatible with this device

Tags: ios, testflight

Please help as I am unable to install in iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 via Testflight.

a. Testflight
The Testflight message says "This build is incompatible with your device. Requires iOS 9.1 and later. Compatible with (... list of devices). Now this list does not include iPhone 4s and iPhone 5. I wonder why.

b. In Xcode:

Build Active Architecture Only = NO
Architectures: armv7, arm 64
Valid Architectures: armv7, armv7s, arm 64
Base sdk iOS 9.1

c. In iTunesConnect:

The Required Capabilities:  Armv7 
Supported Architectures: armv7, arm64

d. iPhone 5 device has iOS 9.1 (not jailbroken)

Observation: The build installs in my other test device, an iPhone 6.
Observation: The build, when directly installed via iTunes (direct ipa installation), installs successfully.

Third pary libraries: AWS, PKHUD, AlamoFire, Charts, Refresher, PixelPerfect, CVCalendar, Google Signin, IQKeyboardManager, Crashlytics

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: yes. letter d above:  iPhone 5 device has iOS 9.1 (not jailbroken). thanks

Comment: hey did you find the solution for this, I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight requires iOS 9.1 and later. Compatible with (... list of devices) ，this sentence has been clearly that you just cannot install whit iPhone 5，and no reason，you just cannot

Answer (score 0):

The build now runs in iPhone 4s and 5. It seems Apple did some changes in either Testflight or the way builds are processed.